# how to load the dyanmic video url in ionic2 iframe

Tags: android, ios, angular, ionic2

iframe working while we give direct url it working fine, but we given into dynamic url it does not working, why?

It say error cannot GET/Video

```
<div  *ngIf="video">
   <iframe src="video" width="100%" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Please give any idea.

Comment: Have you already tried by using `DomSanitizer`?

Comment: No..can you explain me

Comment: In your .ts code add `import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';` , add it in the constructor `constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, ...` and then in the html code it'd be like `<iframe src="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video)" ...` But I don't know if the issue is related to this. Could you please add more information about the error you're getting?

Comment: i have tried your code but it returns this error SafeValue must use [property]=binding: "video url here " (see http://g.co/ng/security#xss)

Comment: Oops, what a silly mistake, it should be like this: `<iframe [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video)" ...`. Notice that `src` is now `[src]`

Comment: Sorry...It's working fine.thank you so much for guiding me..

Comment: Gladto hear that! I'll add it as an answer so it could help other SO users with the same issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `DomSanitizer` to fix it.

In your .ts code add

`import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

add it in the constructor

`constructor(public domSanitizer: DomSanitizer, ...){...}`

and then in the html code it'd be like

`<iframe [src]="domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(video)" ...`